# How to delete the rows from one file having the particular column text in other file through shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Situation: We are having two files in different paths on server. One file i.e. FILE A is in reject folder and the other FILE B is in the archive folder. we are reading the FILE A from reject folder and picking up the word after the text "ITEM:" and then search it in FILE B, If it is found then i have to delete the entire row from FILE B having that word.

### INPUT:

File A:

```
hi my name is himansh agarwal.
My employee id is x56723
I live in Banaglore
I have an ITEM: WORDPRESS
```

FILE B:

```
Hi My name is joseph.
i live in miami.
I dont go to office
I dont have an WORDPRESS.
i am very hungry.
I love to go out.
```

### OUTPUT:

File B should be renamed as FILE B_1 and the text inside it should not contain the line having the text WORDPRESS.
FILE B:

```
Hi My name is joseph.
i live in miami.
I dont go to office
i am very hungry.
I love to go out.
```

Comment: What have you tried? How did it fail? Can you provide sample input files and the expected output?

Comment: please edit your question and add informations, it will be much more readable, and then delete this comments

Answer (score 0):

You can pick out the text with awk:

```
awk '$0 ~ /ITEM: / { sub(/^.*ITEM: /,"",$0); print $0; }' file_a
```

You can exclude a line from a file using `grep -v`

```
grep -v WORDPRESS file_b
```

You can use command substitution to feed the result of one command as a parameter to a second command:

```
grep -v "$(echo WORDPRESS)" file_b
```

You can output the result of a command to a file:

```
echo Test > file_b2
```

This gives:

```
grep -v "$(awk '$0 ~ /ITEM: / { sub(/^.*ITEM: /,"",$0); print $0; }' file_a)" file_b > file_b_1
```

(This assumes that the output is file B_1, not file B. The latter can be acheived with a few `mv` commands)

(You can do it with spaces in filenames, just quite the filenames everywhere then)